# Hibernate with JPARepository or CRUDRepository (without Spring)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, crud

I have many classes:

DAO User:

```
public interface UserDao {

    User findById(int id);

    void save(User user);

    void update(User user);

    void delete(User user);

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

DaoImpl User:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public User findById(int id) {
    ...
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
    ...
    return users;
    }
}
```

OR

VpnDao

```
public interface VpnDao {

    Vpn findById(byte id);

    void save(Vpn vpn);

    void update(Vpn vpn);

    void delete(Vpn vpn);

    List<Vpn> findAll();
}
```

VpnDaoImpl

```
public class VpnDaoImpl implements VpnDao {

    @Override
    public Vpn findById(byte id) {
    ...
        return vpn;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Vpn vpn) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Vpn vpn) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Vpn vpn) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vpn> findAll() {
    ...
        return vpnList;
    }
}
```

and about 20 more similar classes that have the same CRUD methods.
I created the RepositoryDAO class:

```
@Log4j2
public class RepositoryDAO {

    public static void save(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    public static void update(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    public static void delete(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

and implemented repeated methods in it.

I don't like this solution :(

I couldn't bring all the repeated methods to the RepositoryDAO class

UserDaoImpl class is now:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public User findById(int id) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        User user = session.get(User.class, id);
        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        RepositoryDAO.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        RepositoryDAO.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {
        RepositoryDAO.delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("From User", User.class).list();
        session.close();
        return users;
    }
}
```

I know that there is a JpaRepository or CrudRepository in Spring.
But our project does not use Spring.

Please tell me how to do something similar to JpaRepository or CrudRepository without Spring (only Hibernate)?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the dao pattern with default behaviour, extend the default behavior in your custom Dao.

Have a GenericDao.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface GenericDao<T extends Serializable, Id extends Serializable> {
    T findById(Id id);

    T save(T entity);
}
```

Have a Default implementation inside GenericDaoImpl

```
package org.elephant.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T extends Serializable, Id extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, Id> {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

public GenericDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public T findById(Id id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.find(persistentClass, id);
}

@Override
public T save(T entity) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Serializable savedEntity = session.save(entity);
    return persistentClass.cast(savedEntity);
}
```

}

The specific implementation can be like this. VpnDao will have the default methods inherited from GenericDaoImpl. If any customization needed, override/implement it in VanDao.java

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class VpnDao implements GenericDaoImpl<Vpn, Long>{
    public VpnDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you areus.

I add class RepositoryCRUD:

```
@Log4j2
public abstract class RepositoryCRUD {

    static <T> T findById(Class<T> type, Object id) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        T t = session.get(type, (Serializable) id);
        session.close();
        return t;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<T> authorizationHistoryList = session.createQuery("From " + type.getName(), type).list();
        session.close();
        return authorizationHistoryList;
    }

    public static void save(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    public static void update(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    public static void delete(Object obj) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(obj);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            log.error(x);
            if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

And my class VpnDaoImpl now:

```
public class VpnDaoImpl implements VpnDao {

    @Override
    public Vpn findById(byte id) {
        return RepositoryCRUD.findById(Vpn.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Vpn vpn) {
        RepositoryCRUD.save(vpn);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Vpn vpn) {
        RepositoryCRUD.update(vpn);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Vpn vpn) {
        RepositoryCRUD.delete(vpn);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vpn> findAll() {
        return RepositoryCRUD.findAll(Vpn.class);
    }

}
```